# 404 Not Found when the form is empty on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forms, request

I have a form in which I register technicians, the form keeps perfectly in database when the form is full, but when I try to send the empty form to show me the validation errors, I get "404 error
Not Found"

This is the form

```
<form class="needs-validation shadow rounded py-3 px-3" action="{{ route('tecnicos.store')}}" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    @include('tecnicos._form')
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="icon-save"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Guardar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is the tecnicos._form

```xml
@csrf
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-3 ">
    <label><span class="icon-switch_account"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Primer Nombre</label>
    <input type="text" 
           name="nombre_1"
           class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm border-1 @error ('nombre_1') is-invalid @enderror"
           placeholder="Primer Nombre"
           value="{{old('nombre_1', $tecnico->nombre_1)}}">
    @error ('nombre_1')
      <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        <strong>{{ $message }} </strong>
      </span>
    @enderror
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-3">
    <label><span class="icon-switch_account"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Segundo Nombre </label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre_2" class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm border-1" placeholder="Segundo Nombre" value="{{old('nombre_2', $tecnico->nombre_2)}}">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-3">
    <label><span class="icon-switch_account"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Primer Apellido </label>
    <input type="text"
           name="apellido_1"
           class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm border-1 @error ('apellido_1') is-invalid @enderror"
           placeholder="Primer Apellido"
           value="{{old('apellido_1', $tecnico->apellido_1)}}">
    @error ('apellido_1')
      <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        <strong>{{ $message }} </strong>
      </span>
    @enderror
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-3">
    <label><span class="icon-switch_account"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Segundo Apellido </label>
    <input type="text"
           name="apellido_2"
           class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm border-1 @error ('apellido_2') is-invalid @enderror"
           placeholder="Segundo Apellido"
           value="{{old('apellido_2', $tecnico->apellido_2)}}">
    @error ('apellido_2')
      <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        <strong>{{ $message }} </strong>
      </span>
    @enderror
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-3">
    <label><span class="icon-archive"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Tipo Documento</label>
    <select id="tipo_documento"
            name="tipo_documento"
            class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm border-1 @error ('tipo_documento') is-invalid @enderror">
      <option></option>
      <option selected>{{old('tipo_documento', $tecnico->tipo_documento)}}</option>
      <option>CC</option>
      <option>TI</option>
      <option>RC</option>
    </select>
    @error ('tipo_documento')
      <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        <strong>{{ $message }} </strong>
      </span>
    @enderror
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-3">
  <label><span class="icon-looks_one"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Numero de documento</label>
  <input type="number"
         name="numero_documento"
         class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm border-1 @error ('numero_documento') is-invalid @enderror"
         placeholder="Numero de documento"
         value="{{old('numero_documento', $tecnico->numero_documento)}}">
  @error ('numero_documento')
    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
      <strong>{{ $message }} </strong>
    </span>
  @enderror
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-3">
    <label><span class="icon-label_important"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sexo</label>
    <select id="sexo"
            name="sexo"
            class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm border-1 @error ('sexo') is-invalid @enderror">
      <option selected>{{old('sexo', $tecnico->sexo)}}</option>
      <option></option>
      <option>M</option>
      <option>F</option>
    </select>
    @error ('sexo')
      <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        <strong>{{ $message }} </strong>
      </span>
    @enderror
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-3">
    <label><span class="icon-contact_phone"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Telefono</label>
    <input type="number"
           name="telefono"
           class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm border-1" 
           placeholder="Numero de telefono"
           value="{{old('telefono', $tecnico->telefono)}}">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-3">
    <label><span class="icon-home_filled"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dirección</label>
    <input type="text"
           name="direccion"
           class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm border-1" 
           placeholder="Direccion"
           value="{{old('direccion', $tecnico->direccion)}}">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-3">
    <label><span class="icon-face"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Nombre de usuario</label>
    <input type="text"
           name="nombre_login"
           class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm border-1  @error ('nombre_login') is-invalid @enderror"
           placeholder="Nombre de usuario"
           value="{{old('nombre_login', $tecnico->nombre_login)}}">
    @error ('nombre_login')
      <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        <strong>{{ $message }} </strong>
      </span>
    @enderror
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-3">
    <label><span class="icon-fingerprint"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Contraseña</label>
    <input type="password"
           name="contrasena"
           class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm border-1 @error ('contrasena') is-invalid @enderror"
           placeholder="Contraseña"
           value="{{old('contrasena', $tecnico->contrasena)}}">
    @error ('contrasena')
      <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        <strong>{{ $message }} </strong>
      </span>
    @enderror
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-3">
    <label><span class="icon-school"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Profesion</label>
    <input type="text"
           name="profesion"
           class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm border-1 @error ('profesion') is-invalid @enderror" placeholder="Profesion"
           value="{{old('profesion', $tecnico->profesion)}}">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-3">
    <label><span class="icon-work_outline"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Cargo</label>
    <input type="text"
           name="cargo"
           class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm border-1 @error ('cargo') is-invalid @enderror"
           placeholder="Cargo"
           value="{{old('cargo', $tecnico->cargo)}}">
  </div>
</div>
```

These are the routes:

```php
Route::post('tecnicos/store', 'TecnicosController@store')->name('tecnicos.store')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('tecnicos', 'TecnicosController@index')->name('tecnicos.index')->middleware('auth');;
```

This is the Controller:

```php
public function store(SaveTecnicoRequest $request)
{
    Tecnico::create($request->validated());
    return redirect()->route('tecnicos.index');
}
```

This is the Request:

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'nombre_1'         => 'required',
        'nombre_2'         => 'nullable',
        'apellido_1'       => 'required',
        'apellido_2'       => 'required',
        'tipo_documento'   => 'required',
        'numero_documento' => 'required',
        'sexo'             => 'required',
        'telefono'         => 'nullable',
        'direccion'        => 'nullable',
        'nombre_login'     => 'required',
        'contrasena'       => 'required',
        'profesion'        => 'nullable',
        'cargo'            => 'nullable',
    ];
}
```

I am getting 404 error Not Found

```
|        | GET|HEAD  | tecnicos                       | tecnicos.index         | App\Http\Controllers\TecnicosController@index  | web,auth |
|        | POST      | tecnicos/create                | tecnicos.create        | App\Http\Controllers\TecnicosController@create | web,auth |
|        | POST      | tecnicos/store                 | tecnicos.store         | App\Http\Controllers\TecnicosController@store  | web,auth |
|        | GET|HEAD  | tecnicos/{id}                  | tecnicos.show          | App\Http\Controllers\TecnicosController@show   | web,auth |
|        | GET|HEAD  | tecnicos/{id}/edit             | tecnicos.edit          | App\Http\Controllers\TecnicosController@edit   | web,auth |
|        | PATCH     | tecnicos/{tecnico}             | tecnicos.update        | App\Http\Controllers\TecnicosController@update | web,auth |
|        | DELETE    | tecnicos/{tecnico}             | tecnicos.destroy       | App\Http\Controllers\TecnicosController@destroy
```

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code in `resources/views/tecnicos/_form.blade.php`

Comment: Please can you show the output of `php artisan route:list`

Comment: Your `tecnicos/create` URI is set to only accept POST requests. Typically this would be a GET request that shows the form. You can confirm by telling us what URL is giving you the 404 error.

Comment: Lo solucioné cambiando el orden de mis rutas en el archivo web.php, muchas gracias a todos :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your routes file:

```
Route::get('tecnicos/create', [TecnicosController::class, 'create']);
```